# Can I receive UDP messages to a single host/port from two separate physical links on Windows system

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, winsock2

I want to know the difference between "in theory" and "in practice" in a networking context. I don't want to rely on testing it in case the result is not representative of all situations.

I have several deployed installations with multiple nodes, each node in which is a Windows PC with both motherboard network adapter, and additional network card providing extra adapters. There are physical connections to devices dedicated to each node as well as connections between the nodes. I don't know specifically what connects to what at adapter level, and it may change from site to site, installation to installation, but I can always rely on some connection being available from node to node, and node to device.

Currently, a receiving thread on each node takes UDP messages from those dedicated devices addressed to the node at a specific address/port combination. There is no mention of the network adapter in the addressing. Conceptually - "in theory" - this means that I could send a UDP packet on any adapter or any physical connection and have it received by the thread receiving from the addressed host/port.

"In practice", is this what happens, or will one adapter in effect "claim" the host/port and somehow deny access to messages that try to come via other adapters? Does it depend on whether the socket is also use to send as well as receive?

Motivation: dedicated devices currently send UDP messages to each host node. I now have a need to send messages between nodes. Because the messages relate directly to those dedicated devices, I am considering addressing them to the same host/port, which would mean that UDP messages then came in on two different physical channels. Will this be reliable?

Comment: IPv4 or IPv6?  Unicast or multicast (or broadcast)?

Comment: At least IPv4 peer-to-peer, but if there are differences with other options, it would be useful to note them, don't you think?

Comment: Typically each network adapter has its own IP separate IP address, so if the packets are being sent via unicast, the sending programs would need to know the IP address of each of the adapters they want to send to.  If they are sending via multicast or broadcast, OTOH, then the packets should arrive at the sockets of all network adapters that are physically part of the network (who are joined to the multicast group, in the multicast case).

Comment: The 'weak end system model' mentioned in the IP RFCs makes this possible, but you can't rely on it.